# How to make a total for each query and put it into one table

Tags: mariadb

I have 2 queries to collect data but how to get the total like below format:

[image]

```
select b.number as ticket_id,
       d.name as reported_by,
       b.created as reported_date,
       f.topic as help_topic,
       c.subject,
       max(h.poster) as it_respond,
       max(h.body) as answer,
       g.name as status
from ost_staff a, ost_ticket b, ost_ticket__cdata c, ost_user d, ost_ticket_priority e,ost_help_topic f,ost_ticket_status g,ost_thread_entry h
where c.subject like '%unlink%' 
and b.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
and b.user_id = d.id
and c.priority = e.priority_id
and b.topic_id = f.topic_id
and b.status_id = g.id
and b.ticket_id = h.thread_id
and a.staff_id = h.staff_id 
and b.created BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 23:59:00'
group by b.number
order by b.created desc;



select b.number as ticket_id,
       d.name as reported_by,
       b.created as reported_date,
       f.topic as help_topic,
       c.subject,
       max(h.poster) as it_respond,
       max(h.body) as answer,
       g.name as status
from ost_staff a, ost_ticket b, ost_ticket__cdata c, ost_user d, ost_ticket_priority e,ost_help_topic f,ost_ticket_status g,ost_thread_entry h
where c.subject like '%unlink%' 
and b.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
and b.user_id = d.id
and c.priority = e.priority_id
and b.topic_id = f.topic_id
and b.status_id = g.id
and b.ticket_id = h.thread_id
and a.staff_id = h.staff_id 
and b.created BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and '2022-12-31 23:59:00'
group by b.number
order by b.created desc;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] and construct your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query with `GROUP BY YEAR(b.created)`

Something like:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.created),
       SUM(...)
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY YEAR(b.created);
```

Comment: It's look like `SELECT ... UNION SELECT...` case.